# Using server-side processing, how do I presort a column with NULL as last?

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I have a table that has a column with both numeric and NULL values. I'd like the default view to be sorted by this column, in ascending order, but put the NULLs as last.

Pure php/mysql, I can use the negative operator like so:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY -tbl.subNum DESC
```

Or I can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY tbl.subNum IS NOT NULL DESC, tbl.subNum ASC
```

This will sort the table by values ascending, keeping the NULLs last:

```
050-R4
067-R1
116-R1
NULL
NULL
```

I'm trying to use Datatable's server-side processing (the simple one). I have this set as the option for presorting:

```
"order": [[ 0, 'desc' ]],
```

But this will sort the values in descending order. If I put "asc", it will put the NULLs first.

How could the -sort be implemented? Or is there another way to do this? Thanks

Edit 1: Added a different way to show the ORDER BY using MySQL

Edit 2: Replaced dummy values with actual values I have

Comment: Wow, in all my years working on queries and the back end, I've never seen an order by with conditions, that is awesome. Thanks for teaching me this.

I have removed my answer as yours is much easier (and faster) than mine. 

Unfortunately I do not have php experience to answer your datatable problem but it theoretically looks correct. My question would be, does clicking the column (and that code) trigger another query or is it just sorting the objects? You should be able to implement a custom comparator for the latter.

Comment: I had actually created an extra column in a table because of this ORDER BY null last problem, until I ran into that little trick with the negative operator. Anyway, I have a very, very crude working implementation for now. I don't like it. It's essentially hard coding a sort order and disabling the column sort options. But that will have to do until I can figure this out. Thanks again!

Comment: IS NULL ASC achieves the same thing, right? Is that easier to code?

Comment: @Strawberry No. While it does sort the NULLs last, it doesn't sort the column correct (I get this: 261-R1, 264-R1, 197-R1).